# How to not generate infer_objects in makeppfile

Tags: makefile, makepp

```
makepplog:       infer_objects called with seed objects `decompsim_fmod_test_wrapper_tblink_stub.o'
```

Makepp is inferring that i need to create the object file corresponding to my CPP file. But i dont need that. How do i stop makepp from doing that?

Thanks in advance.

[some references](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PFEIFFER/makepp-2.0.98.2/makepplog)